# HTML returned to jQuery method not formed correctly

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, decode

I have a jQuery Ajax method that expects HTML to be returned. The js function url goes to a JsonResult method in ASP.NET MVC. I am using stringbuilder to build the HTML and it looks correct when I use watch in VS. However when it returns the HTML to the page I don't believe it has been decoded properly, it's not a list of anchor tags.

**My javascript**

```
 function getPanDocs(memberNum) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetPandoraDocs',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                MembershipNumber: memberNum 
            },
            success: function (success) {
                $('.pandoraDoc' + memberNum).html(success);
            }
        });
```

**Controller method**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetPandoraDocs(string MembershipNumber)
        {
            Business.Pandora.Pandora p = new Business.Pandora.Pandora();
            string DocLinks =  p.GetDocsById(MembershipNumber);

            return Json(new { success = DocLinks }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Class method for looping through entity set and building anchor tags**

```
public string GetDocsById(string MembershipNumber)
        {

            DataLayer.Pandora.Pandora Pandora = new DataLayer.Pandora.Pandora();
            List<vwPandora2CheckOff> PandoraList = Pandora.GetPandoraDocsById(MembershipNumber);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("<ul>");
            foreach (var item in PandoraList)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<li>");
                string r = item.StoragePath.Replace("\\\\s-documation\\IME_Pandora", "http://pandora.imeche.org/fileshare"); 
                sb.AppendLine("<a href=\" " + r + item.StorageName + "\" target=\"_blank\" >");
                sb.AppendLine("link to document");
                sb.AppendLine("</a>");
                sb.AppendLine("</li>");
            }
            sb.AppendLine("</ul>");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

[image]

[image]

My problem is the html is not rendering properly, and am not sure if it's an error in c# code or js code.

Comment: Why are you returning a JSON string if you want it to be HTML? Just change to `ActionResult` and return it as partial.

Comment: @AndreiV Do I still have to return Json if my Method type is an ActionResult. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: No, there's no need for JSON.

Comment: @AndreiV I don't have a view called GetPandoraDocs so I am not sure what my method is returning? If I return view I get error code 500, can't find view of that name.

Comment: You're right. Try this: `return ContentResult(DocLinks, "text/html");`.

Comment: @AndreiV Thanks you that worked. The logic in the controller needed to be changed. I left my javaScript exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using the actuall XHR-object instead of the responseText, try:

```
function getPanDocs(memberNum) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/Home/GetPandoraDocs',
       dataType: 'html',
       data: {
          MembershipNumber: memberNum 
       },
       success: function (success) {
          $('.pandoraDoc' + memberNum).html(success.responseText);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sending the object from controller. So you have access the html as success.success

```
function getPanDocs(memberNum) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetPandoraDocs',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            MembershipNumber: memberNum 
        },
        success: function (success) {
            $('.pandoraDoc' + memberNum).html(***success.success***);
        }
    });
}
```